# can't open file 'hello_world.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm learning code using 'python crash course Second Edition' and one of the first setups is learning to run 'python_world.py' from a terminal. I'm running the program in Mac. Whenever I put in the code to run the code it gives me this error message:

```
Last login: Fri Nov  6 03:01:42 on ttys000
richardortiz-caballero@Richards-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd Desktop
richardortiz-caballero@Richards-MacBook-Pro Desktop % ls
Screen Shot 2020-08-27 at 12.07.12 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-09-14 at 11.11.37 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-09-17 at 11.10.25 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-10-07 at 1.14.24 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-10-07 at 2.00.35 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-10-07 at 3.42.37 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-10-11 at 10.44.14 PM.png
Screen Shot 2020-10-15 at 8.05.42 PM.png
python_work
richardortiz-caballero@Richards-MacBook-Pro Desktop % ls python_work
hello_world.py
richardortiz-caballero@Richards-MacBook-Pro Desktop % python hello_world.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'hello_world.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: `python python_work/hello_world.py`

Comment: `cd python_work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in the directory of the file for it to run. Before typing `python hello_world.py` you need to enter the directory. So use `cd python_work` first.

Alternatively if you want to run it from the desktop directory, just use the full path when running it:
`python python_work/hello_world.py`

Comment: on mac, use `/` instead of \`\\` when defining path.